# Manually Creating Casper -rw File

Tags: persistence

I was wondering if there was a way to create the casper -rw file for persistence manually, i.e. via terminal. I've been using Ubuntu 14.04 Live USB with persistence and it ran fine for the last two weeks. Last night, I was installing a bunch of apps (or at least, I thought I was) and I got a few errors after which the terminal froze. I had no idea what went wrong, so I just forced shut down and fell asleep.

This morning, I tried to boot my netbook and the screen went blank after the grub menu and just stayed like that. I figured I must've accidentally updated the kernel and it messed up the system. So I plugged in another USB with another OS in my netbook, booted, browsed to the drive where the casper -rw file was located and deleted it.

This solved one problem. I could boot into Ubuntu alright, except I just didn't have persistence. So is there a way to manually create the persistence file WHILE I'm running Ubuntu? I don't want to do another fresh install as I only have two drives (one for backup and one for Ubuntu) and my backup drive's running Porteus and it always fails to create bootable USBs due to some module issue.

I would also like to know if there's a way to stop Ubuntu from updating kernel so as not to get in the same situation again in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

1) To create casper-rw via terminal, you can can enter the following 2 commands one after the other, replacing 512 with any other number of MBs you want for your casper-rw file's size:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=512

mkfs.ext3 -L casper-rw -F casper-rw
```

2) To prevent kernel upgrades, you can install **Synaptic Package Manager**, select the **installed** linux image package(s) (linux-image-xxxxxxxxxx), and then choose **Package > Lock Version** from the menu.

Answer (score 4):

### Boot with the boot option `toram`

Boot (live-only) with the boot option `toram` to be able do to 'anything' with the boot drive, edit it or unplug it without affecting the running operating system.

`toram` makes the content originally from the iso file copied to RAM (and it will be mounted on `/cdrom`).

Now you can **unmount all partitions on the boot drive**. It means that you will be allowed to edit the partition table, or even install an operating system.

### Ways to create persistence

You can use the following methods to create persistence

- mount the FAT32 partition with read-write permissions and create a **casper-rw file** as described in the other answers to your question, a file with a file system inside.
- if you are booting via grub, use **gparted** to shrink the  FAT32 partition and after that use the unallocated space to create a new partition with the ext2 file system or (ext4 file system and later remove journaling) and add the label `casper-rw`. This partition can be bigger than 4 GB, which is a big advantage. (Ubuntu cannot use a casper-rw partition for persistence in the same drive (the boot drive) when booting via syslinux, but it can if the casper-rw partition is in another drive.)
- install **mkusb** temporarily and use it to create a new persistent live drive, but in this case I would really recommend that you get a new cheap USB pendrive, that you can use for the live system, and install the persistent live system into the other drive.
- download and **clone from a compressed image file** to a persistent live system or an installed system (like a system is installed in small devices like mobile phones and Raspberry Pi). This can be done with mkusb in Ubuntu and with Win32DiskImager in Windows.

### Links

[askubuntu.com/questions/928755/can-you-install-the-os-onto-the-usb-you-are-using-to-boot-the-iso-from/928777#928777](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928755/can-you-install-the-os-onto-the-usb-you-are-using-to-boot-the-iso-from/928777#928777)

[Yes, it works with the following recipe :-)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from/855298#855298)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed)

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/sp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/sp)

[wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager)

Answer (score 2):

If the casper-rw file is on a FAT32 formatted device (which many bootable USB drives use), you might consider:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/cdrom/casper-rw bs=1MiB count=4095
```

- `dd`:  Command to write raw data
- `if=/dev/zero`:  Read from device which generates noll (0 value) bytes.
- `of=/cdrom/casper-rw`:  The output file where the casper-rw file lives.  You may need to change this depending on what's mounted where.  The live Ubuntu system typically mounts the root device (USB stick or CD/DVD) at /cdrom.
- `bs=1MiB`:  Tell `dd` how big blocks to write.  1MiB = 1024 * 1024 bytes.
- `count=4095`:  Files on FAT32 can be up to 4GB in size.  4095 * 1MB is just shy of 4GB.

You may need to mount `/cdrom` as read-write (or wherever your bootable device is mounted):

```
mount | grep /cdrom
```

You should see a line like:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

The `/cdrom` device is mounted in this case on `/dev/sdb1`.  To mount it read-write, you would do:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /cdrom -o remount,rw
```

This will mount the USB drive already mounted on `/cdrom` with the `remount,rw` option which says literally `remount read-write`

Then you can use the dd command to create your persistence file and use the mkfs command mentioned above to format it.

NOTE:  You will probably need to reboot for the persistence file to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 16.04.I used YUMI to create USB.I made new persistent file and switched to it from old one.

make new persistent file.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1M count=1024
```

When make fs,put label“casper-rw".This is mandetary.

```
sudo mkfs.ext3 -L casper-rw -F test
```

copy files to new image from old image.I used tar to copy files,because when I used‘cp -ar *’ to copy files,the os hanged up.

```
mkdir mnt1 mnt2
sudo mount casper-rw mnt1
sudo mount test mnt2
cd mnt1
sudo tar cvpzf ../backup.tgz * 2> ../error.log
cd ../mnt2
sudo tar zxvf ../backup.tgz 2> ../error2.log
```

change the persistent file name in grub configuration.Persistent file name can be different from “casper-rw”.I used YUMI to create USB.the grub configuration file is “ubuntu.lst”.YUMI uses grub4dos 0.4.6a.

```
set CASPER=/multiboot/ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-amd64/casper-rw
↓
set CASPER=/multiboot/ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-amd64/test
```

Or you can rename test to casper-rw on windows machine.