# Will installing Ubuntu on an USB via a VM in a Mac work for booting?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi, macbook

I'm planning on making a Lubuntu USB installation for a friend of mine. His device is a MacBook Pro 13 inch late 2011.

My plan is to get a USB stick, passthrough it to virtualbox with EFI enabled, install Ubuntu on the USB stick then give it to him so that he can choose to boot from it in his Macbook when needed.

Please keep in mind that **I don't want to dd the ISO to the USB. I want to make a complete and persistent installation of Ubuntu on the USB**.

My questions are:

- Will this work?
- Will the existing OSX bootloader be affected?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212336/1091774) can get you started?

Comment: You haven't provided release details... as Lubuntu switched from LXDE to LXQt, switched installers, plus the boot process was altered by upstream Ubuntu so I have no idea what system you're asking about.  All releases of Lubuntu are tested using persistent storage (and all work!), though testing does not include macbooks (I'm not aware of any tester who has one). I can't see how OSX bootloader would be impacted.. but your question as written is without specifics (no clues as to software stack you're asking about provided)

Comment: FYI:  Persistent storage isn't created using the `dd` process..  There are many ways the ISO can be written to media; the most tested I'm aware of is with `mkusb` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb at least by Lubuntu/Ubuntu members (most other tools are tested only in cloning or `dd` type writes). Other *flavors* might also have tested tools too... however your link with `dd` & persistence doesn't make sense to me.