# Problem during installation from USB: BOOT ERROR

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I've been trying to install Ubuntu from a USB stick created by Universal USB installer and have changed the BIOS settings to install from USB. But during boot the system displays: `BOOT ERROR _`, and after I press enter the system resumes booting to Windows XP.

The system is 32 bit, 2 GB RAM and currently uses Windows XP. The Ubuntu .iso file was downloaded from Ubuntu's official website. Also, I'm unable to open any of the official Ubuntu documentation from Google chrome on Windows.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by documentation: you can't access a webpage? As for the boot problem, did you see this question and answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/326843/a-usb-flash-drive-failed-to-boot-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Unetbootin:

- Install unetbootin. You can download for windows from [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).
- Open the software, choose your ISO and USB-drive. After that click "ok".
- Restart your computer and make it so the computer runs from the USB at start-up. (You'll need to go to the BIOS)

About you being unable to open ubuntu-documentation, we need more information.

Comment: Universal USB installer is in windows.

Comment: @GuyfromAmsterdam, thanks. Unetbootin is cross-platform though, so it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answers .unetbootin solved the problem i was having.